# Disable "Use default voicemail number"

Tags: voicemail

I am using Lumia 730, windows 10, i am unable to find "Use default voicemail number" to disable it as one of my contact got synced up with it and unable to remove it.
please suggest and guide me to remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried unlinking it from the contact?

Comment: I deleted the number from the contact and checked it still showing as voice mail...